# Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 halts on bcmwl-kernel-source(i386)?

Tags: wireless, 10.04, 32-bit

I've read through the relevant posts, and don't find an answer.

**Problem**: I install from disk Ubuntu 14.04.LTS 32-bit. At boot, Ubuntu gives a wireless error

```
[81.275055] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode5.fw" not found
[81.275074] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode5.fw" not found
[81.275084] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware and download the correct firmware for this driver version. Please carefully read all instructions on this website.
```

Then I get to choose "Try" or "Install" Ubuntu. I install and get to fill in everything and it installs, and always halts on

```
Configuring bcmwl-kernel-source(i386)
```

**Question**: How can I install Ubuntu, without the wireless thing?

**System**: Fujitsu Siemens, Celeron 1.6GHz, 1 Gb RAM.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for responding. My apologies for returning to my question months afterwards...  The problem was caused by an option for 3rd party software / updates option, after the regional/time setup stage...  If the 3rd party thing is unchecked, the installation is successful, without any wireless complaints.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's your wireless card causing this problem?
Or is it just stopping at that point?
At the absolute worst you might have to remove the Broadcom card altogether.
However I feel it's unlikely that it is the broadcom card causing the problem!
If you can access the bios you may be able to disable the on board card in the bios settings?
It might help if you say what model of Desktop you have?

Before you assume it is the broadcom card try booting from the live CD using the nomodeset switch at the end of the boot parameter? In my limited experience it might be your graphics card that is the real problem!

Once you are booted you can then configure your wireless card properly!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the Ubuntu installer is trying to install the wrong driver for your wireless device. Please try installing without selecting 'Download updates while installing.' http://leekaelin.co.uk/downloads/TechSpot/Linux_Guides/Ubuntu_11_10/Ubuntu_11_10_Capture2.JPG Note that it refers to wireless drivers.

After Ubuntu installs, please check here for the method to install the correct driver for your device: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)